# Flexbox and text-overflow:ellipsis don't mix?

Tags: css

My code is very simple:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="not-flex">
  <span>I am text. I should overflow. When I overflow, I should have an ellipsis at the end.</span>
</div>

<div id="flex">
  <span>I am text. I should overflow. When I overflow, I should have an ellipsis at the end.</span>
</div>
```

Why does flexbox not allow my `text-overflow:ellipsis`, and what can I do to make it work?

Comment: It seems [it shouldn't](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=912434)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the overflow stuff on the flex box container, you need to put it on the child element.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita magnam dolore, ipsam architecto, amet iusto. Doloremque minima inventore eius reiciendis corporis officiis impedit iure vitae voluptates, iste nesciunt, labore natus!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the W3C spec, this is the anticipated behavior, [despite](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285943) the [huge](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Sep/0089.html) [number](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Sep/0090.html) of [discussions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=912434) [about](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=912434) it:

### Text Overflow ([spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow))

> This property specifies rendering when inline content overflows its
>   **block container element** ("the block") in its inline progression
>   direction that has ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’.

### Flex ([spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#flex-containers))

> Flex containers are **not block containers**

Comment: Hmm... that's disappointing. Any way to make flex containers behave like `inline-block` or similar?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - not off the top of my head, but will revert if I dig anything up :)